# When using overflow hidden - how to center an inner image?

Tags: css

on my homepage I display images in a 100px tall DIV.
The images are all over 100px+ so I use a div with the CSS property of overflow:hidden
to easily trim off the extra pixels.

But the images don't look so good.
Is there a way for me the center them vertically?
This would make the "trim off" be the same for top and bottom.

http://billetagent.eweb703.discountasp.net/Arrangementer.aspx

thanks!

Comment: Are the pictures all the same height?

Comment: no, that would be too easy :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put the image as a `background-image` on the `<a>` element with `background-position: 50% 50%` (centered vertical and horizontal).

```
<a ... style="background: url() no-repeat 50% 50%;"></a>
```

<del>(Provided that the images are at least 100px tall. Otherwise they will not align to top top.)</del> (Oh, you've already stated this. Great.)

On the now empty `<a>` element you can furthermore add `display: block; height: 100px` to have a clickable area of the same size as the (visible) image.